# How to use long division to compute the reciprocal $1/Q(s)$ of a generic polynomial?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, divisibility, partial-fractions

[In these notes](http://mb.math.cas.cz/full/135/1/mb135_1_5.pdf) (pag 3, pdf alert) the author observes that, given a complex polynomial $Q(s)=q_0 + q_1 s+ ... + q_m s^m$ with $q_0\neq0$, "*using the long-division algorithm*", we have

$$\frac{1}{Q(s)}=\left(\frac{1}{q_0}-\frac{q_1 s}{q_0^2}\right) + s^2 \frac{R(s)}{Q(s)},\tag1$$
for some polynomial $R$.

I'm aware of what [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) is, but I don't see how to apply it here. Normally, if I were to compute $p/q$, I would find a polynomial that multiplied by $q$ gives the same leading order term as $p$ and so on. But this assumes that the order of $p$ is larger than that of $q$, which is not the case for $1/Q(s)$ if I am to think about it as "*$1$ divided by $Q$*".

This actually looks closer to a [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), but then again that would usually involve polynomials in the denominator of both factors in the RHS, which we do not have here.

So where does (1) come from?

Comment: I think your author is talking about doing long division of polynomials, but in reverse. That is, arrange the denominator $Q$ in *ascending* order of degree. Then your first term in the quotient will be the reciprocal of the constant coefficient of $Q$. Multiply this by $Q$ and subtract from $1$, etc. Nothing to do with partial fractions. If you need more details, I can put them in an answer, but it will be a mess.

Comment: @Lubin ah! I never thought of doing "division" that way, nice. If you feel like writing an answer I'll appreciate it and accept it. But also if you think it's too much work don't worry, the suggestion is already sufficient to get me going so if you don't write an answer I will

Comment: @Lubin on second thought, I am actually not so sure I see the analogy with division clearly. As per my answer below, I now understand how to derive these formulas, but the procedure looks more like finding approximate polynomial inverses than "division with respect to a different monomial ordering". If you could sketch what exactly you meant that would be great (no need to go in detail with the calculations if you don't want to)

Comment: Too late now, I’ll see whether I have the energy for it tomorrow. But your self-answer looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We apply long division starting from the constant term, and then the $s$ term:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                \dfrac1{q_0}-\dfrac{q_1}{q_0^2}s+\dots  \\[-1pt]
q_0+q_1s+\dots \enclose{longdiv}{\hspace{7pt}1+\hspace{7pt}0s+\dots} \\[-1pt]
     \underline{1+\dfrac{q_1}{q_0}s+\dots} \\[1pt]
                -\dfrac{q_1}{q_0}s+\dots  \\[1pt]
     \underline{-\dfrac{q_1}{q_0}s+\dots} \\[1pt]
                                   \dots & = s^2R(s)
\end{array}
$$

where "$\dots$" are the $\mathcal O(s^2)$ remainders.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to
$$Q(s)\left(\frac{1}{q_0} -\frac{q_1}{q_0^2}s\right) = 1 - s^2 R(s).$$

To see this, use the expansion $Q(s)=\sum_{k=0}^n q_k s^k$:
$$ Q(s)\left(\frac{1}{q_0} -\frac{q_1}{q_0^2}s\right) = \\
  1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{q_k}{q_0} - \frac{q_1 q_k}{q_0^2} s \right) s^k =
  1 + s^2 \underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^n \left[\frac{(q_0 - q_1) q_k}{q_0^2}\right] s^{k-2}}_{\equiv -R(s)}.
$$
As pointed out in the comments of question, this process can be understood from a more general perspective as a "division" with respect to a different order of the monomials.

We can also generalise this idea: we can always find a polynomial $P$ of degree $1\le \ell\le\deg Q$ such that 
$$Q(s)P(s) = 1 + s^\ell R(s)$$
where $R$ is a polynomial $R(0)\neq0$.
We can understand this procedure as finding approximate polynomial inverses of $Q$.

A concrete example of this type of division is
$$\frac{1}{3+2x+x^2}=\left(\frac13 - \frac29 x\right) + \frac{x^2}{9(3+2x+x^2)},$$
or equivalently,
$$(3+2x+x^2)\left(\frac13 - \frac29 x\right) = 1 - \frac{1}{9}x^2.$$
Using a polynomial $P$ of degree $\ell=3$ we would instead get
$$(3+2x+x^2)\frac19\left(3-2x + \frac13 x^2\right) = 1 + x^3 R(x).$$

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/505827/173147) is also somewhat related.