# Polynomial division and series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, polynomials

When I perform polynomial long division on $\frac{1}{1-x}$, I get the sequence $1+x+x^2+x^3+...$
I do not get the restriction of $|x|<1$. Is this a mistake by me or something I just have to add to the problem for it to make sense? I know that in [Polynomial long division: different answers when reordering terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505817/polynomial-long-division-different-answers-when-reordering-terms?rq=1) they mention it, but I do not really feel they respond to why one has no restriction and the other one does.

Comment: The partial sum is $$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$ The term $x^{n+1}$ only converges to $0$ for $n\to\infty$ , if we have $|x|<1$

Comment: It is not claer for me which term you divide by which term. Add more details.

Comment: @callculus42 You can only do the division in two different ways and only one leads to the series $1+x+x^2+...$

Comment: But that is not actually polynomial long division which would just give $0$ with remainder $1$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709846/how-to-use-long-division-to-compute-the-reciprocal-1-qs-of-a-generic-polynom?noredirect=1&lq=1 @Peter

Answer (score 1):

In the answers you mention, both series are correct but in different regions. Both ways to divide are correct. If you stop the division algorithm at any point you get identities, correct for any $x$..

The restriction $|x|<1$ arises when you consider the full series. For convergence you need your remainders $x^n/(1-x)$ to converge to zero as $n\to\infty$, and there you need $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the polynmial long division algorithm on $\frac{1}{1-x}$, after $n$ steps you can say that $$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}+\frac{x^n}{x-1}$$  Where the $\frac{x^n}{x-1}$ is the "error", if you want this error to go to zero as $n\to \infty$ then you must have that $|x|<1$.